# How to store variables within variables in Batch?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I am trying to store a concatenated set of variables into a newly SET variable. When I add a variable into another variable it doesn't seem to actually get set correctly. I'm curious if BATCH can store variables within variables, or if I have to do formatting beyond what I currently have:

Example: The 'oldDirectory' variable should display the same thing as  `"%progdata%\%datetime%"`

```
@echo off

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%DATE%") do (
    SET YYYY=%%c
    SET MM=%%a
    SET DD=%%b
)
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:." %%a in ("%TIME%") do (
    SET HH24=%%a
    SET MI=%%b
    SET SS=%%c
)

SET datetime=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%_%HH24%%MI%%SS%
SET progdata=C:\ProgramData

@echo on    

IF EXIST  "%progdata%" ( 
echo Found  %progdata%
SET oldDirectory="%progdata%\%datetime%"
echo %oldDirectory%
) 
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a standard `DELAYED EXPANSION` problem, discussed endlessly on SO.

When batch encounters a `"Block statement"` - that is typically a parenthesised statement spread over many lines such as your `IF EXIST` then the entire statement is parsed through to the closing parenthesis AND at this time, ANY `%var%` is replaced by the value of that variable as it stands **WHEN THE STATEMENT IS PARSED**

Consequently, your `ECHO %olddirectory%` is replaced by `ECHO` since `olddirectory` has no value **AT PARSE TIME** and executing `ECHO` will report `ECHO is On/Off` `progdata` on the other hand **IS** set at parse-time and hence `echo Found  %progdata%` is replaced by `echo Found  C:\ProgramData`

The very simplest cure is to move the `ECHO` statement outside of the `block`

```
IF EXIST  "%progdata%" ( 
 echo Found  %progdata%
 SET oldDirectory="%progdata%\%datetime%"
)
echo Olddirectory=%oldDirectory%
```

(I added the `olddirectory=` so that the `echo` statement finds something to echo if `olddirectory` is not set)

The second easiest way to display the value is

```
IF EXIST  "%progdata%" ( 
 echo Found  %progdata%
 SET oldDirectory="%progdata%\%datetime%"
 CALL echo %%oldDirectory%%
)
```

Here, the `ECHO` command is not expanded in the context of the `IF`, but in the context of the `CALL` which acquires its environment from the run-time value of the `IF` context.

The third easiest way to display the value is by using the `delayedexpansion` option of a `setlocal` command. An NT batch command traditionally starts

```
@echo off
setlocal
```

which suppresses `echoing` and establishes a local environment. Any changes to the local environment are backed out when an `endlocal` or end-of-file is reached in the `setlocal`'s context. If this mantra is consistently followed, we don't get the situation where a variable is established by one batch and the environment is 'dirty' for the next. Consider running your original twice within the same `cmd` session. `progdata`, and all of the other variables you are establishing would remain set for the second coming - and hence `olddirectory` may be set by your first invocation, and retain that stale data if for some reason it's not EXPLICITLY set in the second. `setlocal` backs all those changes out for you.

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` adds an extra facility to the mix. Whereas `%var%` is resolved to the **PARSE-TIME** value of `var`, if `delayedexpansion` has been invoked then `!var!` is resolved to the **RUN-TIME** value - as it changes in a `FOR` loop...

Hence, adding

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

at a strategic point (after the `@echo off` until you're off your training wheels...) would allow you to make a simple change to the display of `olddirectory`

```
IF EXIST  "%progdata%" ( 
 echo Found  %progdata%
 SET oldDirectory="%progdata%\%datetime%"
 echo !oldDirectory!
)
```

Comment: I appreciated the in depth answer as to the problem including the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try with :

```
CALL SET oldDirectory="%progdata%\%datetime%"
CALL ECHO %oldDirectory%
```

Comment: CALL SET is still leaving %oldDirectory% blank it appears.

Comment: I've edited the answer.With CALL SET you don't need double percent .But if you want to display the oldDirectory inside IF you'll need to use CALL ECHO

Comment: When trying your revised answer, it is still not listing anything for oldDirectory which to me indicates oldDirectory is empty?

Comment: It should not be...The example works on my machine , so I'm not sure where the problem can be.

Answer (score 2):

First method:

```
IF EXIST  "%progdata%" ( 
echo Found  %progdata%
SET oldDirectory="%%progdata%%\%%datetime%%"
call echo %oldDirectory%
)
```

Second method:

```
IF EXIST  "%progdata%" ( 
echo Found  %progdata%
SET oldDirectory="!progdata!\!datetime!"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %oldDirectory%
)
```

An interesting point is that `echo %oldDirectory%` command display *the current value* of `progdata` and `datetime` variables with the *same value* of `oldDirectory`!

**EDIT**: *Example added*

```
@echo off

set progdata=C:\ProgramData

echo First method:
SET oldDirectory="%%progdata%%\%%date:/=%%_%%time::=%%"
call echo %oldDirectory%

echo Second method:
SET oldDirectory="!progdata!\!date:/=!_!time::=!"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %oldDirectory%
```

Output:

```
First method:
"C:\ProgramData\14082013_211303.20"
Second method:
"C:\ProgramData\14082013_211303.21"
```

Comment: When trying either of your suggestions my last call to display oldDirectory is blank. As its coded now I get a line back that states: ECHO is on.

Comment: @FuzzEvans: Be sure that the two variables have right values before use they in `oldDirectory`. See my added example above.